# Share a GUI (JFrame) between agent calls

Tags: java, swing, lotus-notes

I have a java agents that opens a GUI. When the agent is finished the GUI remains open. Whenever I start the agent again, or start another agent I would like to use the same GUI again.

Is there any way to detect an open GUI or to share the reference between the agents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Window class and iterate through all created instances

```
   /**
     * Returns an array of all {@code Window}s, both owned and ownerless,
     * created by this application.
     * If called from an applet, the array includes only the {@code Window}s
     * accessible by that applet.
     * <p>
     * <b>Warning:</b> this method may return system created windows, such
     * as a print dialog. Applications should not assume the existence of
     * these dialogs, nor should an application assume anything about these
     * dialogs such as component positions, <code>LayoutManager</code>s
     * or serialization.
     *
     * @see Frame#getFrames
     * @see Window#getOwnerlessWindows
     *
     * @since 1.6
     */
public static Window[] getWindows()
```

also Frame has

```
public static Frame[] getFrames()
```

Comment: Does that actually work in the context with Lotus Notes? Agents are normally separate entities.

Comment: @Simon O'Doherty I think that nothing to do with Agents, Agent returns Object that you caled (Stas+1)

Comment: I am trying it now. I do find the frames. But the dispose of a frame is not called (at least it seams so) so I am just closing the existing frame. That seems to work fine

Comment: Got it working now, not exactly what I wanted, but good enough. I get the frames, check if it is "mine" and close it.